# SQL IF Condition in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am relatively new to advanced database queries and stored procedures, and I am having an issue with the third `UPDATE` statement in the procedure below, the one within the `IF` code block.  The issue is that I need to add membership numbers to these accounts, so the first iteration of `UPDATE` adds `lp.ID_1` to my temporary table, while the second iteration adds `lp.ID_2` to the temporary table.  The third iteration needs to take the remaining rows from the original `INSERT` statement (where `ident` should still be NULL) and concatenate the `ident` column with both `ID_1` and `ID_2`, as these accounts have both memberships.

I have tried several conditions in the `IF` block, but seem to come up short of a solution each time.

```
USE [database_1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_procedure_1] @acct char(8) 

AS

WITH X AS 
 (
    select distinct st.ship2, t.name, null AS ident 
    from sales_table st
    INNER JOIN accounts_table t ON st.ship2 = t.acct
    where st.bill2 = @acct
 )
SELECT x.ship2 AS s_acct
      ,x.name
      ,COALESCE(ident, lp.ID_1 +', '+ lp.ID_1 , lp.ID_2 , lp.ID_2 , '' ) AS Ident 
FROM X 
LEFT JOIN lp_table lp ON x.ship2 = lp.acct COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
WHERE COALESCE(ident, lp.ID_2 +', '+ lp.ID_1 , lp.ID_1 , lp.ID_2 , '' ) <> ''

select * from X
where ident is not null
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the if statement and just have the `UPDATE` statement get called anyways? You do have the check for if ident is null so it should do what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: "`take the remaining rows ... and concatenate the ident column with both ID_1 and ID_2, as these accounts have both memberships.`"  No! **Don't do that!** This is a _deeply flawed schema_. If accounts can have multiple memberships, you need a separate table to map accounts to memberships. **NEVER** put csv data into a column!

Comment: @JohnOdom, if I remove the `IF` condition, the procedure runs as normal without the last `UPDATE` having any affect.  In other words, it runs as if the last `UPDATE` was not there.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, what you are saying is that for `ID_1` I should insert those rows into `#temp_table_1`, for `ID_2` insert those into `#temp_table_2`, and for the concatenation I should have `#temp_table_3`?  When I do this, at the end should I simply be able to `UNION` them all together for one result set?

Comment: No. You should have a real table (not a temp table) with two fields: one for account number and one for membership number. Then you write a JOIN when you need to know about account memberships.

Comment: The very `select * FROM x` is not required any more, the query itself is a select query and should return the desired result set.

Comment: I am still getting the error `The multi-part identifier "x.ship2" could not be bound.` as well as that same error for all the `x.column` areas

Comment: The error was due to the `X` vs the `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this whole update and left joins shebang can be written in one single query without any updates or temp tables

```
;WITH X AS 
 (
    select distinct st.ship2, t.name, null AS ident 
    from sales_table st
    INNER JOIN account_table t ON st.ship2 = t.acct
    where st.bill2 = @acct
 )
SELECT x.ship2 AS s_acct
      ,x.name
      ,COALESCE(ident, lp.ID_2 +', '+ lp.ID_1 , lp.ID_1 , lp.ID_2 , '' ) AS Ident 
FROM X 
LEFT JOIN lp_table lp ON x.ship2 = lp.acct COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
WHERE COALESCE(ident, lp.ID_2 +', '+ lp.ID_1 , lp.ID_1 , lp.ID_2 , '' ) <> ''
```

Comment: Where is the `X` coming from?

Comment: `X` is the name of CTE `Common Table expression` a possible replacement for temp table in your case.

Comment: Ok, I like where this is going but I am not exactly sure how to implement this in a stored procedure. I am getting the error that `x.ship2` `x.name` cannot be bound

Comment: Take all of your code out and put this query in, update your question once you have done it so I can see where you going wrong , as it is I cannot see how it would produce this error that you speak of.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect your code changes, it is probably my rookie understanding of SQL that is causing these errors as I have never used CTE before

Comment: I fixed the errors and this works, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The second update query won't work. The first update query is updating all ident values the #temp_table rows that have a matching "acct" with lp_table. The second query is looking at exactly the same set of rows which you have just updated with the added condition that you are only interested in ones where ident is null.... however in the first step you just made sure none were null. I think what you are looking to do is identify which rows were not updated by the first query assuming some of the idents are updated to Null. I am assuming some of the data in ID_1\ID_2 is null where as the acct columns will always be populated with data. If my assumption is correct you can do the following:

Change your query to:

```
create table #temp_table
(
    s_acct char(8) null,
    name varchar(50) null,
    ident varchar(10) null
)

insert into #temp_table
select distinct st.ship2, t.name, null
from sales_table st, account_table t
where st.bill2 = @acct
and st.ship2 = t.acct

update #temp_table
set ident = COALESCE(lp.ID_1, lp.ID_2, 'BOTH LPS ARE NULL?')
from lp_table lp
where #temp_table.s_acct = lp.acct COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS


select * from #temp_table
where ident is not null
```

And as per M.Ali's answer it can be improved to remove any temp table useage and do it in one go. I have included this for completeness.

Comment: in the first `UPDATE` it should only insert `ID_1`, so for those accounts that have not been assigned `ID_1` the `ident` column is still NULL, therefore my second `UPDATE` works correctly.  The third `UPDATE` is where I am getting confused.